# Only allow access to specific service running on computer in Demilitarized Zone over internet

Tags: ports, remote-server, dmz

If a computer (running different services such as ftp and ssh) is placed on a Demilitarized Zone, will all of its services automatically be accessed by anyone on the internet?

If the answer is yes, then is it possible to only allow a specific service such as ftp, to be accessed over the internet and block access to all the other servers?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a DMZ is that you have two firewalls, one between the system and your LAN and one between the system and the global Internet.

A skilled administrator will of course configure the firewall facing the internet to only allow those services which are required by the server.

Answer (score 0):

> f a computer (running different services such as ftp and ssh) is
>   placed on a Demilitarized Zone, will all of its services automatically
>   be accessed by anyone on the internet?

That depends upon the rulebase already in place on the firewall. However, the answer to your question is *most likely* **no** - based on the assumption that a NAT rule will not be in place for a new asset.

> If the answer is yes, then is it possible to only allow a specific
>   service such as ftp, to be accessed over the internet and block access
>   to all the other servers?

**Yes**, this is possible. Ideally there would also be switch ACL's in place that would prevent the assets in the same DMZ from communicating with each other as well.